# Where is the start point of this makefile

Tags: c, postgresql, makefile

The following is a makefile I encountered in Postgres, I don't understand how it works. I saw some simple Makefile examples where they have commands to compile, but this one seems to be different. Could anyone explain how this makefile works? Basically I need to understand this one before I modify it for my purpose.

```
subdir = src/backend/access/transam
top_builddir = ../../../..
include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global

OBJS = clog.o multixact.o \
    xlogreader.o xlogutils.o

include $(top_srcdir)/src/backend/common.mk

xlog.o: xlog.c $(top_srcdir)/src/include/catalog/catversion.h
```

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subdir = src/backend/access/transam
top_builddir = ../../../..
```

Set some variables

```
include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global
```

Include a global makefile (presumably uses the two previously set variables in some way).

```
OBJS = clog.o multixact.o \
    xlogreader.o xlogutils.o
```

Create an `OBJS` variable for the things to be built in this directory (I assume).

```
include $(top_srcdir)/src/backend/common.mk
```

Include another makefile (which presumably uses `OBJS` and defines rules/flags/etc. for building files).

```
xlog.o: xlog.c $(top_srcdir)/src/include/catalog/catversion.h
```

Explicitly handle prerequisites to the `xlog.o` target file (presumably because putting this in `OBJS` would do something undesirable).

For more about what `subdir` or `OBJS` is used for exactly (or what else you can set in this file) you would need to read and understand `src/Makefile.global` and `src/backend/common.mk`.